# Grails 4.1.0 application throwing exception 'TABLE_NAME' not found when try to execute sql.rows

Tags: mysql, database, grails, dependency-injection, h2

I try to execute the query using

```
groovy.sql.Sql
sql.rows("select * from table_name") //all query string in samll case
OR
sql.rows("select * from 'table_name'") //all query string in small letters
```

Then when this statement executed I encountered the following error:

```
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "TABLE_NAME" not found; SQL statement:
select * from `table_name` where field1 > -1 and field2 = 0 limit 100 [42102-199]
        at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:111)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "LOCATION" not found; SQL statement:
select * from `table_name` where field1 > -1 and field2 = 0 limit 100 [42102-199]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:451)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7146)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1895)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:2641)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2788)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:2636)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:2469)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:2440)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:814)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:788)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:760)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:683)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:627)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:565)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1292)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcStatement.java:78)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy161.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at groovy.sql.Sql$QueryCommand.runQuery(Sql.java:4740)
        at groovy.sql.Sql$AbstractQueryCommand.execute(Sql.java:4654)
        at groovy.sql.Sql.rows(Sql.java:1764)
        at groovy.sql.Sql.rows(Sql.java:1681)
        at groovy.sql.Sql$rows.call(Unknown Source)
        at app.MYService.setMyFeildValue(MYService.groovy:4765)
        at app.MYService$setMyFeildValue.call(Unknown Source)
        at app.MYServiceJob.execute(MYServiceJob.groovy:26)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:104)
        ... 2 common frames omitted
```

Since this exception is related to h2database and then I tried to remove runtimeOnly dependency of com.h2database:h2 and also change my application.yml dataSource as following

```
environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate : "update" # one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            driverClassName : "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" # override the above entry
            dialect : org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
            url : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBName"
            username: "user"
            password: "My_PASSWORD"
            properties:
                maxActive : 50
                maxIdle : 25
                minIdle : 5
                initialSize : 5

                numTestsPerEvictionRun : 3
                maxWait : 10000

                testOnBorrow : true
                testWhileIdle : true
                testOnReturn : true

                validationQuery: "SELECT 1"

                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis : 1000 * 60 * 5
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis : 1000 * 60 * 5
```

But still my application tries to load the data from in memory h2database.
I also try by cleaning the dependency caches and refresh them but nothing works for me.

The code sniipen for my query execution:

```
package app
import groovy.sql.Sql
class MyService{
   def dataSource
   def setMyFeildValue(){
     def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
     sql.rows("select * from table_name")
   }
}
```

(Edited)
I try to connect with the database explicitly by using

def sql = Sql.newInstance(db.url,db.user,db.password,db.driver)
then try to execute the sql.rows("select * from tablename")

then its works.
Now the main question is why the dataSource is not getting a connection to mysqlDB from the application.yml and why it still connecting to h2database.

Comment: It looks like application.yml is correct for connecting to MySQL. Try commenting out the h2 database default dataSource.

Comment: @wubbalubba I tried with that also, but nothing went in my favor.
So I tried to create a new application and understand things more clearly by adding one module at a time.